# Prove that $\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt5}2}$ is not in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt5)$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Prove that
$$\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt5}2} \not \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt5)$$

I think I should start taking the next equation $\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt5}2}=p+q\sqrt5$ but I don't see how to continue from here

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: The thing I can think of is to square both sides, compare the rational part and the irrational part, and see if $p$ and $q$ are rational numbers.

Comment: If it's possible to express $\sqrt {\frac {1 + \sqrt {5}} {2}} = p + q \sqrt {5},$ for some $p,q \in \mathbb Q$ then $16 p^4 - 8 p^2 + 5 = 0$ which doesn't have any real solution for $p.$

Comment: Find its irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb Q$. Show that it's irreducible and of degree $4$, therefore its roots cannot be contained in a degree two extension.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 4):

Let $K = \mathbb Q(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})$. Note that $N_{K/\mathbb Q}(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}) = -1$. If $\alpha = \sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}} \in K$, then

$$-1 =  N_{K/\mathbb Q}(\alpha^2) = N_{K/\mathbb Q}(\alpha)^2.$$

Since $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha) \in \mathbb Q$, this is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}}=p+q\sqrt5$
$\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}=(p+q\sqrt5)^2=(p^2+5q^2)+2pq\sqrt5$
$p^2+5q^2=\frac12=2pq$
$p,q\neq 0$
$(p/q)^2-2(p/q)+5=0$
let $r=p/q,r\in\Bbb Q$
$r^2-2r+5=0$
$0\leq(r-1)^2=-4$
contradiction